# difference in probability meaning

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I want to understand the difference between the following

What is the probability of getting at least 10 heads in 60 coin tosses?

and

What is the probability of **ever** getting at least 10 heads in 60 coin tosses?

Can you please explain the two?

Comment: Out of context I see no difference. In context, perhaps the second one could mean "what is the probability of ever getting at least 10 heads in one of infinitely many sequences of 60 coin tosses?" Or something like that. But that seems rather artificial.

Comment: Source(s)? $ $ $ $

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503631/why-crow-is-even-mentioned-in-this-probability-puzzle

Comment: The first refers to a single set of $60$ tosses, and the second refers to an infinite number of sets of $60$ tosses (in which case, the probability is obviously $1$).

Comment: @barakmanos Please answer the question in the light of the other stackexchange post which is in the comment. See Comment #2

Comment: As written I find the "ever" questions quite unclear. It seems that the interpretation barak manos and I suggested is the only one that makes sense and would also give a different answer than the questions with no "ever".

Comment: @lan we live in a world where things are not always clear. Did you see the stackexchange post in comment #2. See Questions 2 and 4 from that if you have time

Comment: @user2979872 I meant the ones from the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of getting at least $10$ heads in $60$ coin tosses is:

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{n=10}^{60}\binom{60}{n}}{2^{60}}=0.9999999$$

---

The probability of ever getting at least $10$ heads in $60$ coin tosses is:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}1-(1-0.9999999)^{n}=1$$